# How use to NSIS textbox, button event?

Tags: nsis

I want to pass external .exe parameters via IP textbox and Key textbox.

This is my Setup code. The external .exe receives three parameters.

The first is the product name, the second is the ip, the third is the key.

You do not know how to write nsis to pass external parameters.

How to use is confusing.

**Under Code(Setup.nsi)**

```
## input lincesekey, ip
Function PageInputLicenseInfo
  ReserveFile "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini"
  !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_EXTRACT "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini"
  !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini"
FunctionEnd

## I want to pass external .exe parameters
Function MyCustomLicense
  #IP
  !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R0 "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 3" "State"
  ${If} $R0 == "1"
  Exec '"$INSTDIR\JCertFileGenerator.exe "/${PRODUCT_NAME},$R0""'
  ${EndIf}
  #KEY
  !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R1 "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 4" "State"
  ${If} $R1 == "1"
  Exec '"$INSTDIR\JCertFileGenerator.exe "/${PRODUCT_NAME},$R0,$R1""'
  ${EndIf}
  ## external .exe
  !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R2 "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 5" "State"
  ${If} $R2 == "1"
  File "..\ADAgent\bin\Release\JCertFileGenerator.exe"
  Exec '"$INSTDIR\JCertFileGenerator.exe "/${PRODUCT_NAME},$R0,$R1""'
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

**Under Code(pageInputLicenseInfo.ini)**

```
Ini file generated by the HM NIS Edit IO designer.
[Settings]
NumFields=5

[Field 1]
  Type=Label
  Text=IP
  Left=6
  Right=37
  Top=8
  Bottom=19

  [Field 2]
  Type=Label
  Text=License Key
  Left=5
  Right=64
  Top=24
  Bottom=35

  [Field 3]
  Type=Text
  Left=65
  Right=274
  Top=4
  Bottom=16
  State=1

[Field 4]
Type=Text
Left=65
Right=274
Top=20
Bottom=33
State=1

[Field 5]
Type=Button
Text=확인
Flags=NOTIFY
Left=225
Right=275
Top=40
Bottom=56
State=1
```

I would appreciate if you write a method for passing parameters to an external .exe using fields 3,4,5.

Comment: Field 5 is a button, it does not make sense to use it as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command-line quotes are wrong and you also fail to extract JCertFileGenerator.exe in some of the code-paths!

Quoting should look like this:

```
Exec '"c:\my path\program.exe" param1 "param with spaces" /param3'
```

And here is a silly example:

```
Unicode True
!define PRODUCT_NAME "Hello World"
Name "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
OutFile Test.exe
!include MUI.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include InstallOptions.nsh

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
Page Custom LicensekeyPageCreate LicensekeyPageNotify
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function .onInit
; I'm writing the .ini directly here because this is just an example
InitPluginsDir
FileOpen $0 "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" a
FileWriteUTF16LE /BOM $0 ""
FileClose $0
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Settings" NumFields 5
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 1" Type Label
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 1" Text IP
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 1" Left 6
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 1" Right 37
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 1" Top 8
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 1" Bottom 19
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 2" Type Label
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 2" Text "License Key"
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 2" Left 5
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 2" Right 64
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 2" Top 24
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 2" Bottom 35
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 3" Type Text
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 3" Left 65
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 3" Right 274
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 3" Top 4
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 3" Bottom 16
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 3" State 1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 4" Type Text
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 4" Left 65
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 4" Right 274
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 4" Top 20
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 4" Bottom 33
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 4" State 1
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 5" Type Button
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 5" Text "${U+d655}${U+c778}"
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 5" Flags NOTIFY
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 5" Left 225
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 5" Right 275
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 5" Top 40
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 5" Bottom 56
WriteIniStr "$PluginsDir\pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 5" State 1
FunctionEnd


Function LicenseKeyPageCreate
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini"
FunctionEnd


Function LicensekeyPageNotify
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $0 "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Settings" "State"
${If} $0 = 5 ; Was the button clicked?
    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R0 "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 3" "State"
    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R1 "pageInputLicenseInfo.ini" "Field 4" "State"
    ExecWait '"cmd.exe" /C echo "${PRODUCT_NAME}" IP=$R0 Key="$R1" &pause'
    Abort ; Stay on the current page
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Executing something in $InstDir before you get to the InstFiles page is usually not a good idea, you might want to use $PluginsDir instead or ask for the license key information after the InstFiles page.